# extract text not part of inner division

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have this code that extracts too much text. 
I am trying to extract only the title from top-content.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
r  = requests.get("https://education.maharashtra.gov.in/saral/27230500360")
data = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
soup.find("div", {"class": "top-content"})
```

How do I extract the name of school that is not part of inner div?
Expected output:

```
BHARATI VIDYAMANDIR HINDI NIGHT HIGH SCHOOL AND JR COLLEGE (27230500360)
```

---

update:

Is it possible to save the text as dict?

```
{27230500360 : "BHARATI VIDYAMANDIR HINDI NIGHT HIGH SCHOOL AND JR COLLEGE"}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. It will get you there:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

req  = requests.get("https://education.maharashtra.gov.in/saral/27230500360")
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text,"lxml")
for item in soup.select("#logo"):
    data = ' '.join(item.text.split())
    item_dict = {data.split(" ")[-1]:' '.join(data.split(" ")[:-1])}
    print(item_dict)
```

Output:

```
{'(27230500360)': 'BHARATI VIDYAMANDIR HINDI NIGHT HIGH SCHOOL AND JR COLLEGE'}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your wanted text is in a div with the `logo` id

```
text = soup.select('#logo')[0].text
print(text.strip())
```

outputs

> BHARATI VIDYAMANDIR HINDI NIGHT HIGH SCHOOL AND JR COLLEGE

Answer (score 1):

To get the school name you can do this

```
>>> text = soup.find('div', {'id': 'logo'}).text.strip()
>>> text
'BHARATI VIDYAMANDIR HINDI NIGHT HIGH SCHOOL AND JR COLLEGE                                                                                                                                                                                                (27230500360)'
```

As you can see there is a lot of whitespace in between `BHARATI VIDYAMANDIR HINDI NIGHT HIGH SCHOOL AND JR COLLEGE` and `(27230500360)`. To delete that, you can use regex.

```
>>> text = re.sub(' +', ' ', text)
>>> text
'BHARATI VIDYAMANDIR HINDI NIGHT HIGH SCHOOL AND JR COLLEGE (27230500360)'
```

In short,

```
>>> re.sub(' +', ' ', soup.find('div', {'id': 'logo'}).text.strip())
'BHARATI VIDYAMANDIR HINDI NIGHT HIGH SCHOOL AND JR COLLEGE (27230500360)'
```